# IKImageView properties not being set in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, ikimageview

I have a IKImageView in Interface Builder and have set the background color to red but it doesn't work when the app is run, it just stays gray.

1. I created a brand new Cocoa (OS X) project in Xcode 4.5 with the Cocoa Application template.
2. Added the Quartz framework
3. Dragged an IKIMageView from the Object library onto my window.
4. Change the color to red.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have the same problem, don't know how to fix it thought...

Answer (score 2):

I set background color by this:

```
_imageView.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor];
```

where `_imageView` is set as `IBOutlet IKImageView *  _imageView;`

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in `IKImageView`.

Better Workaround:
Use `setImageWithURL:` with nil as a parameter and CALayers will be constructed also do not name any method of custom `IKImageView` as `-(void)commonInit`